# Process/thread creation and destruction history or ledger on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, threads

I'm seeing some strange threading behaviour in my Mac (Yosemite 10.10.4). The number of threads shoots up and then goes back down again. Sometimes it stays extremely high, thus exceeding `maxproc` and leading to `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable` messages, even after increasing it to 2048.

Given that threads count towards `maxproc`, I'd like to monitor where this **thread thrashing** is coming from.

`top`, `htop` and `glances` only offer snapshots, but I need a **timestamped log of thread creation and destruction**, including *ownership* and *parenthood*, to accurately identify the problem.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:** Removed my reference to Google Chrome as a potential suspect, to keep the question focused on the thread history or ledger.

Comment: Well, first, there really isn't such a thing as a thread leak. Threads are not a limited resource. Second, every request to get a script or load an image or stylesheet or tell the marketer spying on you that you visited somthing, or client side analytics updates, etc, generates a thread. it would be uncommon for most browsers to use less than 10 threads to load a modern page. Thread creation and destruction is semi-expensive, so most heavily asynchronous apps pool threads and keep them around for use later. So what is your actual problem? threads aren't "consumed". there are infinite threads.

Comment: CONT. A Thread represents a stream of Instructions, so as such, it is the smallest and most atomic unit of processing an app can use. that means every process is executed as at least one thread. In this case, your threads are all idle, they are not executing anything, as evidenced by the low or non-existent CPU usage for these processes. it a thread is not consuming CPU, then it might as well not exist, except for the small amount of work reusing it later will save you, so theres neither a reason to throw it out, nor a reason to be concerned that the process has spawned at least 63 threads.

Comment: Yes, I know what a thread it, but the bottom line is that in Mac OS X and *nix kernels, they count towards `ulimit` and `sysctl` limits. Here's where my system is hitting a limit, possibly due to a spurious application, and that's why I'd like to monitor where that activity is coming from in order to pinpoint the problem down. http://blog.ghostinthemachines.com/2010/01/19/mac-os-x-fork-resource-temporarily-unavailable/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009632/getting-strange-behavior-from-terminal-and-iterm-bash-fork-resource-temporar

Comment: There isn't a builtin/easy way, but dtrace should expose the info you want, but it is a very large versitile tool, so it has a bit of a learning curve, and will require some research. here may be a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5488/gcggv.html Alternately, Roland Smith's answer here may offer you a way to at least determine what PIDs/PPIDs are being created as they show up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269891/monitor-process-creation-in-freebsd . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I think you should correct your comments above, @FrankThomas. (1) Threads are not a limited resource => they can be if they are capped by the OS. In Unix systems, one can set `maxproc` to `unlimited`, but in Mac OS X it is not possible and it's capped to 2048, thus **the number of threads is inherently limited** making them a **limited resource**. (2) HTTP requests to fetch images, CSS, etc from the browser **do not each generate a new thread**! Threads are reused via threadpools, like you later point out. You may want to correct that too. And maybe remove a downvote ;)

Comment: It turns out that there **IS** a built-in an easy way to monitor process/thread creation on Mac OS X in real-time: the **`execsnoop`** tool. I added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to gather some insight thanks to the **`execsnoop`** tool. Description from the man page:

> execsnoop prints details of new processes as they are executed. 
>   Details such as UID, PID and argument listing are printed out.

Example output:

```
[raul@~/bitbar$] sudo execsnoop -v
STRTIME                UID    PID   PPID ARGS
2016 Jan 14 17:56:09     0      1      0 launchd
2016 Jan 14 17:56:09   501  90311      1 influxd
2016 Jan 14 17:56:16   501  90312    321 kcc
2016 Jan 14 17:56:16     0      1      0 launchd
2016 Jan 14 17:56:16     0  90313      1 kcm
2016 Jan 14 17:56:19     0      1      0 launchd
2016 Jan 14 17:56:19   501  90314      1 influxd
```

`execsnoop` uses **DTrace**, and I found this great post with some other scripts/tools: http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/.

In Mac OS X (Darwin) and *nix kernels, threads are represented as processes, and that's why the count towards the `ulimit` and `sysctl` limits.